# Javascript - Passing previous query results into next .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am chaining queries using knex to add additional data to my JSON return object. However i cant seem to understand why i cant passing the reults from one knex.query to the .then() of the second knex query.

CODE:

```
 exports.getApps = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.raw(`
      SELECT *
      FROM APPs
      WHERE VARAPP_PUBLIC_ACTIVE > 0
      ORDER BY VARAPP_PUBLIC_ACTIVE ASC, VARAPP_NAME ASC
    `).then(function(results) {
      if (results[0].length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results[0].length; i++) {
            db.raw(`
              SELECT *
              FROM APPs_Features
              WHERE VARAPP_ID = ?
                ORDER BY VARAPP_ORDER ASC
            `, [results[0][i].VARAPP_ID], i)
            .then(function(features, currentIndex) {
              if (features[0].length > 0) {
                console.log(results[0]);
                console.log(features[0]);

                results[0][currentIndex].Features = features[0];
              } else {
                results[0][currentIndex].Features = null;
              }

            }).catch(function(err) {
              console.error(err);
              reject(err);
            });

          }

          resolve({
            apps: results[0]
          })
      } else {
        resolve({
          error: 'No Apps Found'
        })
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
    });
  })
}
```

That is my full code, as you can see I'm trying to query the apps table, `.then()` loop over the results to then query the Apps_features table and then inject the features results into the original queries results. I am getting an error that reads.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'Features' of undefined
    at C:\Sites\VARNET_Vars\content\appList.js:21:40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the `i` value, not on the chaining.

This cycle will be executed immediately:

`for (var i = 0; i < results[0].length; i++)`

So `i` will be equal to the `results[0].length` when the inner promises have been resolved. 
You can easily test it trying to specify this as static to check if it works:

`results[0][i].Features = features[0];`

In order to fix it, you have to pass the current i to the inner promise invocation and the returned value, in order to not use the value already set at the maximum when resolved the promises.

So you could do something like:

```
exports.getApps = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.raw(`
      SELECT *
      FROM APPs
      WHERE VARAPP_PUBLIC_ACTIVE > 0
      ORDER BY VARAPP_PUBLIC_ACTIVE ASC, VARAPP_NAME ASC
    `).then(function(results) {
      if (results[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].length; i++) {
          elaborate(i, results, reject);   
        }
        resolve({
          apps: results[0]
        })
      } else {
        resolve({
          error: 'No Apps Found'
        })
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
    });
  })

  function elaborate(i, results, reject) {
    db.raw(`
              SELECT *
              FROM APPs_Features
              WHERE VARAPP_ID = ?
                ORDER BY VARAPP_ORDER ASC
            `, [results[0][i].VARAPP_ID], i)
      .then(function(features) {
        if (features[0].length > 0) {
          results[0][i].Features = features[0];
        } else {
          results[0][i].Features = null;
        }

      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense, however im still fairly new to node, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: im sorry but your answer has me confused how to go about implementing your solution

Comment: Best way in these cases is that you manage the `i` value inside the function you are calling and you return it together with `features` in the resolved promise. But are you allowed to work within the specific call `db.raw(`
              SELECT *
              FROM APPs_Features
              WHERE VARAPP_ID = ?
                ORDER BY VARAPP_ORDER ASC
            `, [results[0][i].VARAPP_ID])` ?

Comment: Cool so inside that function, accepts a new parameter, which is the current `i`. And when inside that function you resolve the promise returning `feature`, returns also the current `i` you received, so your `then` function will be `.then(function(features, currentIndex)` and use `currentIndex` instead of `i` inside the block: `results[0][currentIndex].Features = features[0];`.
So the call will be `db.raw(`
              SELECT *
              FROM APPs_Features
              WHERE VARAPP_ID = ?
                ORDER BY VARAPP_ORDER ASC
            `, [results[0][i].VARAPP_ID], i)`

Comment: updated the code in teh question, however im still getting the same error

Comment: can you check inside the `db.raw` function which value of `i` you receive? and then you resolve it in order to be returned?

Comment: i logged currentIndex and its coming back undefined

Comment: if i log `i` within the .then() it returns 7

Comment: let's switch to a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154549/discussion-between-quirimmo-and-charles).